# Cambiar la hora de la BIOS en vez de cambiarlo en el kernel de Linux

Tags: linux, bash, date

La pila de mi ordenador está algo gastada y cada tanto, cuando inicio el sistema, la fecha es el 1 de enero del año 2012.

Tengo un comando para cambiar la hora:

```
sudo ntpdate 1.ar.pool.ntp.org
```

El problema es que cuando reinicio el sistema, la hora vuelve a estar mal. ¿Hay alguna manera de modificar la hora del reloj en la *BIOS* en vez de la hora del Linux?

Me dieron un comando llamado *hclock* o algo parecido, no recuerdo exactamente bien, pero tampoco sé cómo usarlo.

Comment: Suena estupido pero,si lo que quieres es cambiar la hora de la BIOS ¿Por que no entras en la BIOS y la cambias?

Comment: @Capt.Teach Porque cuando entro a la BIOS no sé la fecha y hora actual o me olvido, tampoco tengo reloj de pulsera digital para mirar, me resultaría más cómodo hacerlo desde la terminal de Linux para evitar tener que reiniciar la PC tantas veces.

Comment: Si lo que quieres es cambiar la hora de la BIOS desde Linux , lo que buscas es el comando `hwclock` En este [enlace](https://www.thegeekstuff.com/2013/08/hwclock-examples/?utm_source=tuicool) te dejo una guia de como usar este comando.

Comment: Tengo este error: `hwclock: La ejecución de select() a /dev/rtc0 para esperar una señal de reloj expiró`

Comment: Sobre ese error no puedo ayudarte ya que no tengo experiencia con ese comando, intenta probar los otros por si es algo concreto. Si con `hwclock`no puedes avanzar te recomiendo que cuando tengas la oportunidad mires la opcion de hacerlos desde la BIOS , supongo que tendras movil para ver la hora ;)

Comment: Esto también puede sonar más tonto aún, pero ¿no has pensado en reemplazar la batería desgastada de la *board*? Entiendo que saber un comando para cambiar o configurar la hora desde el S.O. es algo que puede ser necesario, sin embargo, en mi opinión, es más aconsejable realizar el reemplazo de la batería. Saludos

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Cuando tu PC está apagado, usa la pila de la placa base para mantener activa la fecha, como cualquier reloj digital.

Al arrancar, el SO necesita usar la BIOS para obtener acceso al hardware (recordemos que BIOS es Basic Input/Output System). Una vez que se completa la primera fase de arranque, el SO ya tiene acceso directo al hardware y deja de usar la BIOS, aunque antiguamente no era así y dependía de la BIOS para todas las operaciones E/S.

El SO no tiene forma en principio de saber qué hora es, así que se la pregunta a la BIOS. Si la BIOS tiene la fecha mal, el SO no puede solucionarlo porque no conoce otra fecha.

Esto ha cambiado con la llegada de Internet: desde hace unos 20 años, el SO intenta acceder a algún servidor de fechas público (existen muchos, conectados a relojes atómicos de distintos centros de investigación) para actualizar la hora del sistema. Puesto que la hora del sistema y la hora de la BIOS son la misma instancia, generalmente cambiar la hora al sistema operativo es cambiarla a la BIOS.

Tu problema es que el PC *olvida la hora* cada vez que se apaga porque no usa la la fuente de alimentación/poder para mantener el reloj, solo puede usar la pila y la tienes gastada.

Answer (score 1):

A ver si entre todos somos capaces de darte una respuesta perfectamente válida y que quede por aquí para consultas futuras, @ArtEze:

Lo primero y fundamental es que reemplaces la pila de la placa base por una nueva, porque realizar este proceso en cada reinicio es, además de tedioso, absurdo.

Igual es bueno explicar previamente que un equipo tiene  dos relojes, el de hardware (que es el que almacena la BIOS) y el del sistema operativo. No me explayo más en ello a la vista de la respuesta de @Pablo Lozano.
Una vez cambiada la pila por una nueva, lo primero será actualizar la hora del sistema (que podrás ver a priori mediante el comando date). Para ello se usa el comando ntpdate, que requiere permisos de susperusuario, y que toma la hora, efectivamente, de un servidor horario (normalmente de segundo o tercer  nivel, no directamente de esos relojes atómicos con los que actualizan la hora a menudo). Es lo que haces con el comando que expones en tu pregunta, otorgando al comando ntpdate el nombre de un servidor de tiempo como argumento, y efectivamente mediante el protocolo NTP (Network Time Protocol).:

```
sudo ntpdate 1.ar.pool.ntp.org
```

Por lo que veo resides en Argentina. Un vistazo en google nos arrojará direcciones de servidores de tiempo diversos para nuestra franja horaria.

Puedes comprobar mediante el comando date sin parámetros que la hora del sistema ha sido actualizada. (date muestra la hora del sistema, no la de hardware).

> date - print or set the system date and time

(Del man date).

Ahora lo que toca es sincronizar la hora de hardware con la del sistema. Para ello se usa el comando hwclock, herramienta poderosa que, entre otras cosas, permite sincronizar la hora de hardware con la del sistema.

> hwclock is an administration tool for the time clocks.  It can: display the Hardware Clock time; set the Hardware Clock to  a  specified  time; **set the Hardware Clock from the System Clock**; set the System Clock from the Hardware Clock; compensate for Hardware Clock  drift;  correct  the System  Clock  timescale; set the kernel's timezone, NTP timescale, and epoch (Alpha only); and predict future Hardware Clock values  based  on its drift rate.

Sin argumentos, hwclock (sudo hwclock, ya que de nuevo requiere permisos de superusuario) muestra la hora de hardware. Para "exportar" la hora del sistema a la de hardware (que es la que almacena la BIOS al apagar el sistema) basta con añadirle el parámetro -w, o --systohc en formato extendido:

```
sudo hwclock --systohc
```

Por el contrario, la opción -s (o extendida --hctosys) modificaría la hora del sistema (la que arroja el comando date) tomando la hora del reloj de hardware.
Como nota adicional, con el paso del tiempo la hora del sistema y la de hardware no tienen por qué coincidir exactamente:

```
alfonso@foresthost:~$ date
sáb jun 29 00:19:33 CEST 2019
alfonso@foresthost:~$ sudo hwclock
2019-06-29 00:19:40.478027+02:00
```

Yo tengo un desfase de 7 segundos, que equivalen a la pérdida de exactitud de mi reloj de hardware desde que tengo este equipo.

Suerte.